# Asp.net razor: model property is called houndred of times when it really should be called just once

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am quite new to ASP.NET with razor, I think I may have gotten a concept wrong.

All I am doing is instantiating my model, letting it retrieve data from the local db and returning it to the view.

The code is working fine, but when I put a stop point into the beginning of the GET it runs into that stoppoint literally hundreds of times before coming to a result.

This of course impacts performance massively.

Let me show you what I have done (briefly):

My controller has one ref to the model:

```
public class GlobalTaggingController : BaseCmsEditorController
{
     public  GlobalTaggingViewModel model = new GlobalTaggingViewModel();

     public ActionResult Index(string searchword = "")
     {
         return View(model);
     }

     // ... cut for brevity 
}
```

The viewmodel looks like that:

```
public class GlobalTaggingViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public List<NodeModel> MainNodes
    {
        get
        {
            var globalTaggingLocalizedManager = new GlobalTaggingLocalizationManager();
            var manager = new GlobalTaggingManager();
            var mainlevel = manager.GetAllItemsOnLevel(0);
            var subLevel = manager.GetAllItemsOnLevel(1);
            var subsubLevel = manager.GetAllItemsOnLevel(2);
            var resMainCat = new List<NodeModel>();

            // ... cut for brevity
        }
    }
}
```

This is my view (which is very long and has many loops):

```
@model Application.Areas.Administration.Models.GlobalTaggingViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Administration - Video";

    var positionNr = 0;
}


    <form action="@Url.Action("Index")" method="POST" id="mainForm">
        <div class="divHeader Administration">
            <div class="divHeaderInner">
    
    
                                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.MainNodes.Count(); i++)
                                    {
                                        string catId = "CatId" + i.ToString();
                                        string classToHideCatId = "classToHideCatId" + i.ToString();
                                        string rowCounter = "rowCounter" + i.ToString();
    
                                        <tr class="mainCatRow">
                                            <td>
                                                <table class="mytable">
                                                    <thead>
    
                                                    </thead>
    
                                                    <tr class="@rowCounter rowHeight">
                                                        <td class="column0">
                                                            <div>
                                                                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/icons/icon-open.png")" id="@catId" class="buttonLayoutMain" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="column1">
                                                            <table class="tableInCol1">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td class="editButtonClassLeft">
                                                                        <div class="mainCat">
                                                                            @Model.MainNodes[i].name
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td class="editButtonClassRight">
                                                                        <div>
                                                                            <a onclick="javascript:Base.Popup.Open('@Url.Action("Index", "GlobalTaggingEditor", new {area = "Cms", id =  Model.MainNodes[i].Id})', 1236, 800); return false;" href="#" class="ButtonEdit"><span class="mif-pencil"></span></a>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="mainCat mainCol">
                                                                @Model.MainNodes[i].nameEng
                                                            </div>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="mainCat mainCol">
                                                                @Model.MainNodes[i].name
                                                            </div>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="mainCat mainCol">
                                                                @Model.MainNodes[i].nameSpanisch
                                                            </div>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="mainCat mainCol">
                                                                @Model.MainNodes[i].nameFra
                                                            </div>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="mainCat mainCol">
                                                                @Model.MainNodes[i].namePort
                                                            </div>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="mainCat mainCol">
                                                                @Model.MainNodes[i].nameRuss
                                                            </div>
                                                        <td class="column9">
```

Again this is working code, but it is called over and over and over again.
Did I maybe set something up wrong?

EDIT:

Going through my code in single steps, I found out that my model is recreated again once I am going through the razor page.

Specifically here:

```
<td class="column1">
    <table class="tableInCol1">
         <tr>
             <td class="editButtonClassLeft">
                 <div class="mainCat">
                     @Model.MainNodes[i].name
                 </div>
             </td>
             <td class="editButtonClassRight">
                 <div>
                     <a onclick="javascript:Base.Popup.Open('@Url.Action("Index", "GlobalTaggingEditor", new {area = "Cms", id =  Model.MainNodes[i].Id})', 1236, 800); return false;" href="#" class="ButtonEdit"><span class="mif-pencil"></span></a>
                 </div>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
```

Why would that start the model over again?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as I put everything inside the GET of the model, intead of doing it over a constructor, I was able to get around this issue.